# Как нарисовать геометрическую модель пятигранной призмы в OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl

С обычными графическими примитивами проблем нет, а как сделать 3D модель фигуры, не совсем понимаю.
Если в основании пятигранной призмы лежит пятиугольник, то как связать его с высотой призмы?
Либо как сделать параметрическую модель данной призмы - с помощью матрицы объекта?

Закрашивать не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пятигранная призма очень легко представляется с помощью `vertex-triangle` подхода.

Основание такой модели, очевидно, можно представить в виде 3 треугольников, последовательно соединенных в `triangle strip`, т.е как `ABDE` на [**вот этом**](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/0/03/Triangle_Strip.png) изображении, точка `C` должна лежать на стороне `AE`.

*Каждая из вертикальных сторон призмы моделируется с помощью двух треугольников, соединенных схожим образом.*

---

**Соответственно, все, что вам нужно сделать - это правильно расставить вертексы и правильно указать индексы соответствующих треугольников.**

Про часть вопроса, связанную с параметрическим моделированием, к сожалению, ничего не могу сказать, т.к что такое *"матрица объекта"* я себе достаточно слабо представляю. Думаю, тут найдутся люди, разбирающиеся в теме `САПР`, которые смогут вам подсказать.

Comment: то есть, после расстановки вертексов, она будет выглядеть так:
http://shkolo.ru/pryamaya-prizma/
?

Comment: `@Котик_хочет_кушать` наверное знает все!!! О_о!!!